# why cant sed remove white space at the start of my file?

Tags: bash

`top -n1 | tail -n +8 | sed 's/^ [" "]*//g'`

produces the same output as

`top -n1 | tail -n +8`

how do I make sed actually remove the white spaces?

Comment: I removed the pointless details, hopefully this page can help someone out

Comment: Your character class should be `[ ]`, not `[" "]`.

Answer (score 2):

The output of `top` is full of control characters. Pipe it through `od -c` and you'll see that the first character on each line is the ASCII escape character (octal: 033), not a space. To get script-friendly output use `-b` (batch mode).

Comment: I did so many google searches for "special characters in top output" i thought that this is what was up. thanks for confirming, and thanks for the -b and oc -c commands!